# Swift Abort Trap 6 during compile caused by putting a value in @Published String

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

I've already submitted a bug report to Apple (#7654122), but I'm hoping someone might know of a workaround because at this point I'm stuck on my project and can't make forward progress.

```
class BaseData: ObservableObject {
    @Published var pmtstr = "" // <-- here

    // ... bunch of other stuff
}

class DataWhatIsLoanPayment: BaseData {
    // ... other stuff

    override func calculate() {
        super.calculate()

        // ... other stuff

        self.pmtstr = "stuff" // <-- here
    }
}
```

When I set `self.pmtstr = "stuff"` and try to compile, the compiler crashes with Abort Trap 6. If I comment out that line, the app compiles correctly.

If I remove the `@Published` from the initial declaration of `pmtstr`, then the app compiles correctly. If I put the `@Published` back, the compiler crashes with Abort Trap 6.

I need to be able to update this string and publish the results of the calculation in order to make forward progress on developing this app.

Any suggestions for a workaround (or a fix)?

Comment: For which platform did you compile? I tried just by copy-paste for iOS/macOS and all goes well. Xcode 11.4 (11E146).

Comment: just as a possible workaround, did you try super.pmtstr = "stuff" ?

Comment: btw: I created a DataWhatIsLoanPayment object and added it to a view as an environment object to my test View.  It worked without errors - I can't reproduce your problem. I'm using Swift 5.3/Xcode 11.4